# запустить app.js с помощью spawn на node js

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, node.js

Мой код

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');
var st = 'xvfb-run node --harmony';

start('app.js');

function start(nodefile) {
  if (typeof start !== 'string') {
    console.log('Has none file. like this: start("app.js")');
  }
  console.log('Master process is running. ');

  setTimeout(function() {
    var proc = child_process.spawn(st, [nodefile]);

    proc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    proc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    proc.on('exit', function(code) {
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);

      setTimeout(function() {
        delete(proc);
      }, 10000);

      start('app.js');
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

На борту nightmare js работает на ubuntu. А он запускается определенным образом: xvfb-run node --harmony app.js. И он в таком виде выдает ошибку

```
Error: spawn xvfb-run node --harmony ENOENT
```

Как мне правильно запустить?

Comment: Вам node.js недвусмысленно дает понять: `ENOENT` (нет сущности). А значит это, что команда у вас неверная.

Comment: `.spawn('xvfb-run', ['node', '--harmony', nodefile])`. В [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) ясно написано, что аргументы должны быть отдельным массивом (в отличии от `.exec`)